# InverseWaveletTransform not recreating the original image exactly

Tags: wavelet-analysis

I am trying to do DWT steganography. I first obtain the `DiscreteWaveletTransform` of the image as follows

```
dwd = DiscreteWaveletTransform[carrierImage, HaarWavelet[], 1]
(* Out: DiscreteWaveletData[<< DWT >>, < 1 >, {256, 256}] *)
```

This splits the image into four separate images that can be obtained with `dwd[All, "Image"]`, but when I use those with `InverseWaveletTransform` I get a blurred version of the original image. Why is it so?

MWE to recreate the problem:

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
dwd = DiscreteWaveletTransform[img, HaarWavelet[], 1];
newdwd = DiscreteWaveletData[dwd[All, "Image"], HaarWavelet[], DiscreteWaveletTransform];
Row[{
  Show[InverseWaveletTransform[newdwd], ImageSize -> 200],
  Show[InverseWaveletTransform[dwd], ImageSize -> 200]
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For @JasonB it's even worse (image link copied from his comment):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @C.E. - I get a much worse reconstruction than you do:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/RZuml.png

Comment: @JasonB That's interesting, I added it to the question so it becomes even more intriguing at first glance.

Comment: You told the WaveletTransform to use a Haar wavelet. Which wavelet do you suppose the InverseTransfom is using?

Comment: I've never reconstructed a `DiscreteWaveletData` object before.  If you compare the files `FullForm[dwd] >> "test1.txt";
FullForm[newdwd] >> "test2.txt";` you see that test1.txt is 889 lines longer...

Comment: Every test I run returns that `newdwd` is not a properly constructed `DiscreteWaveletData` object.  Try `newdwd["TreeView"]`
and `newdwd[All, "Image"]` versus `dwd["TreeView"]` and
`dwd[All, "Image"]`.  Perhaps you could rephrase the question "How can I reconstruct a discrete wavelet data object from its constituent parts?"

Comment: @bills I think the point is that `newdwd` looks, at first blush, to be exactly the same as `dwd` in the notebook interface. The same wavelet, the same transform, the same dimension etc. Now `{Dimensions@First@#, Quiet@Rest@#} & /@ {dwd, newdwd}` reveals that in one parameter they differ, but it's unclear what that parameter does or if it can be set. Anyway `InverseWaveletTransform` should use the Haar wavelet as it does when it inverts `dwd`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason behind the blurry inverse transformations lies in the fact that a function (`ImageAdjust`) is applied to the wavelet coefficients when you call `DiscreteWaveletData`. And that's not what we want.

---

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];

dwd = DiscreteWaveletTransform[img, HaarWavelet[], 1];

newdwd = DiscreteWaveletData[
        dwd[All, {"Image", "ImageFunction" -> Identity}], HaarWavelet[], 
        DiscreteWaveletTransform];

Row[{Show[InverseWaveletTransform[newdwd], ImageSize -> 200], 
        Show[InverseWaveletTransform[dwd], ImageSize -> 200]}]
```

[image: dwd]